# Overriding CPU Lock in Android

Tags: android, wakelock, android-windowmanager

I've been playing around with windowManager overrides of WakeLocks in android.  I've got it to the point where I can power off the screen so that the video I'm running will "turn off".  However, the CPU remains running and consequently so does the audio.  I'd like to be able to put the device in sleep mode when I click the power button while the video is running.  Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: By default, when you press Power button all wakelocks are released. I do not understand why this behavior differs in your case.

Comment: Wake locks are not released on a power button hit.  If you acquire a partial wake lock and press the power button for sleep mode, you can see the CPU still runs.  If you don't have one and press the power button then you'll see the log activity (at least from your program) go quiet. To my knowledge Wake locks exist primarily to override the power button.

Comment: You're right. Only screen locks are released when you press power button.

Comment: Interesting, I should experiment to see if the overrides of my screen locks by my activity settings are necessary.

Comment: It's not really necessary. You can look here: http://pastebin.com/jdPNA32g I've pasted goToSleepLocked method of PowerManagerService

Comment: Thanks, that ended up being useful for a minor variation on the above task that I was doing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently running a hack that tests the screen state at certain intervals and stops the video (hence the audio) and leaves the CPU running.  I'd be happy if people have a better solution but this is part of the way there.